# Decide the output if a value exists in the group after SQL grouping

Tags: mysql, sql

id, number, user and status are my columns
Here, the column **"status"** is having enum values **'A','D','P' and 'R'**

```
SELECT
    number,
    count(user),
    status
FROM
    table1
GROUP BY
    number
ORDER BY
    id DESC
```

I'm grouping the results from the column **"number"** and if any record of the group contains **'P'** for the **"status"** the result must be **'P'**, Else the result must be the Maximum value in alphabetical order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT number, 
       COUNT(user) counter,
       COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN status = 'P' THEN status END), MAX(status)) status
FROM table1
GROUP BY number
```

If any of the values of `status` for a specific `number` is `'P'` then `MAX(CASE WHEN status = 'P' THEN status END)` will return `'P'` and if none of them is `'P'` it will return `NULL`.
So `COALESCE()` will return `'P'` for the first case or `MAX(status)` for the second case.

Answer (score 1):

Compute auxiliary value holding information if there exists `'P'`, then decide by this value:

```sql
SELECT
    case
      when sum(case when status = 'P' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 then 'P'
      else max(status)
    end,
    number
FROM
    table1
GROUP BY
    number
```

Please state your db vendor. For example in case of Postgres, `count(*) filter (where ...)` could be used too.

Comment: DB Vendor is  MySQL